# JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello guys so now I'm trying to create to do list application using react native and I'm able to make the user add task. Now I want the user to be able to update the Task status by pressing some button (touchableOpacity). I want the touchableOpacity to change color from red to green (if the task is finished) and turn the color from green to red if the task haven't finished. Can someone help me please ? I want to use state for this. But it shows some error

JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text. (19:36)

Here's my code:

```
const Task = (props) => { 
  const[pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
  const onPressHandler = () =>{
    setPressed(!pressed);
  };

    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.taskList}>{props.text}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style=[{backgroundColor pressed ? '#ff3126' : 'green'}, styles.taskStatus] onPress={() => onPressHandler()}>
              <Text style={styles.statusText}>On Going</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are all your imports correct? Maybe check for a typo there.

Comment: yeah it's correct already, I think its because of my syntax

Comment: in the style attribute wrap array in {}

Comment: oke thankyou for the response. I want to ask more question why did the TouchableOpacity become unpressable ? if I move the touchable tag to before <text Tasklist> then it become pressable. But the position become awkward